# Choregrphe の Record Soundで録音した音源の保存場所について

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

ChoregrpheのRecord Soundで録音した音源がどこに保存されているのかわかりません。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

Record Sound の Temporary storage を ON にしている場合は、「cd /tmp」以下に保存されているようです。

参考URL
http://qiita.com/tonosamart/items/8b02243abdb9884b3083
http://qiita.com/tonosamart/items/cbabe47bc6ded3cbe17a